# How to setup Muti theme for multi website in Magento 2.3.5

Tags: custom-theme, magento2.3.5-p1

I am going to create multi websites and stores in magento and i want to setup different theme for each store.

so anyone can have idea about it please share with me.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: you can create multiple theme and set theme on website level

Comment: yes i am created three websites and want to set different theme for each website

Comment: I am created store and store view already